# Align second line link with start of first line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Please check the below snippet.

When a link goes on multiple lines, I'd like the text from all lines below the first one to be aligned with the start (left position) of the first line. The icon should still be vertically aligned with the first line (as it is now).

In other words, in the below example, the word "***longer***" should be aligned below the word "***This***".

I have tried playing with paddings and text-indents without success. Does anyone have a solution?

```css
.column {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="column">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-tree"></span> <a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></span> <a href="#">This is a much longer link</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></span> <a href="#">Hello again</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in css..

```
.column li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
li span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```css
.column {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.column li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="column">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-tree"></span> <a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></span> <a href="#">This is a much longer link</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></span> <a href="#">Hello again</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That will do! Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display:flex` to your `li` and it will work if you want the text to move further away from the icon then use margins too.
Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.column {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.n {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="column">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="n"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-tree"></span></div> <a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="n"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></span></div> <a href="#">This is a much longer link</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="n"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></span></div> <a href="#">Hello again</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If we dont add width to icons and there is flex

```css
.column {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li
{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="column">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-tree" style="background-color:blue;"></span> <a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-car" style="background-color:blue;"></span> <a href="#">This is a much longer link</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-book" style="background-color:blue;"></span> <a href="#">Hello again</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is quite nice, although for some reason now the start of second line in not anymore aligned with the first and third lines...

Comment: @MrUpsidown That is because the icons are of variable size ive updated the answer now you can see the change

Comment: They are not. They all have the exact same width, which is achieved by using `fa-fw` class on the font-awesome icon.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes it is achieved by  fa-fw by while including inline:flex the width changes to the width of the icon that is why it didnt show last time and it shows now after adding the width to the icon

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use a `display: grid;` layout on your `li` tag.

```css
.column {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.column li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="column">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-tree"></span> <a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></span> <a href="#">This is a much longer link</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></span> <a href="#">Hello again</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```